# MVC Ajax with Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I'm trying to create simple Ajax call, but after clicking the link I get a blank page with "Test" string in top left corner:

In my Details view I have:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("test", "AddPositive", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "countDiv" })

<div id="countDiv">
</div>
```

In controller:

```
public string AddPositive()
{
    String test = "Test";
    return (test);
}
```

Action does get called.

In _Layout.cshtml I imported.

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's probably something really simple, but still cannot figure it out after going trough a few beginners tutorials for Ajax. Appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: At the very least you've imported the same javascript file twice.  Don't do that.

Comment: and what do you have on your page before you click on the link. Does your page reload?

Comment: @bobek, yes the page view is loaded fine. After clicking on the link, I get empty page and Test in top left corner. I have both JS files imported.

Comment: @Ben Finkel, sorry about the typo, I have both imported and its the same problem mentioned.

Comment: by getting a page do you mean your page reloads? Did you check with Firebug console if there are any errors??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You are missing jquery and jquery.unobtrusive-ajax file.

Either there i bug in `MicrosoftMvcAjax.js` or M.S. has forgot to mention these files on their [Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533%28VS.98%29.aspx). I hardly use this feature (`@Ajax.ActionLink`) so its tough for me figure out why it didnt worked without jQuery files.

Comment: Thanks, it was <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Must all these 4 scripts be included for the `Ajax.ActionLink` to work? The *Microsoft\*Ajax.js* files don't exist in my *Scripts* folder.

Comment: Update: I'm using MVC5 and it works without the MS files. Only the jQ files are required.

Answer (score 2):

You want to import two different .js files like so:

```
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, I could be wrong, but doesn't your Action need to return an ActionResult?

Comment: returning actionresult or string is not the issue. But yes he should import 2 different files.

Comment: @Praveen Prasad, sorry about the typo, I have both imported and its the same problem mentioned.

Comment: @Ben Finkel, it can be a string as I see in this tutorial :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLiWQkqUoVM